# how to copy a button in layout?

Tags: android, button, copy

i want to make 16 buttons in one XML file but i don't want to make all of them individually ...how can i make it happen , like making one button and then copy it for many times?? 
like this picture :

http://i62.tinypic.com/t7cvie.png

i tried making a button

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button1);
```

what shoud i do next?

and then i want to swipe the buttons so i would have other 16 buttons and go on ....
what should i do? i got confused.
help me?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure if you were looking for this .
But there are multiple ways to reuse your code in android. One of the  way to re-use your button definition that I prefer to use is to define the layout of the button first and include it where ever needed. Each include can be given unique id. Below are the steps to follow:

Define your android button layout in **layout folde**r first. This would be your only definition.

example: my_layout.xml

```
android:gravity="center|bottom" >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_register"
    android:background="@drawable/bordered_rounded_button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    style="@android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
    android:paddingRight="3dp"
    android:shadowColor="#4D56A8"
    android:shadowDx="0"
    android:shadowDy="0"
    android:shadowRadius="5"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:text="@string/button_register"
    android:textColor="@color/WhiteSmoke"
    android:textSize="14sp" 
   />
```

then you can include this in your view/xml 15 times ( or any number of times) with unique id of each include .
like this :

```
<include  android:id="@+id/include_layout_id"
          layout="@layout/my_layout"    <!-- make sure this matches your layout file name-->
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

Good Luck!

Comment: umm thanks this may help, umm i just want to make a quiz/puzzle game (something like "Guess the Brand" or something like that ... and i'm trying to make that part where there are buttons to go to a quiz page (like the pic i shared) , there are 16 buttons there and when you swipe left or right, 16 more buttons appear , but i don't want to write every page ... i guess its like loading 16buttons many times with every swipe... i don't know if i said it well or not...

Comment: If i understood it correctly, you can just collect your info from your activity and upon swipe event, you can redraw the same page. but you need some way to identify which page you are displaying to process logic properly. I would prefer separate page for each swipe though.

Answer (score 1):

The first you must get layout where you want to add buttons, after initialize button and when add it to layout

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id."layout id");

setContentView(new GraphTemperature(getApplicationContext()));

Button newButton = new Button(this);
newButton.setText("New Button");
newButton.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

layout.addView(myButton);
```

put this code in for loop i<=15;

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the same ids in same layout if there behavior is different. So you have to create 16 Buttons in your layout. But put your button definition to your style.xml